# Opening absolute urls in RedwoodJS - SSR

Tags: server-side-rendering, redwoodjs

I have a RedwoodJS App with several routes.
It's very basic for now and I start the development server with `yarn rw dev`.

Now I have created some routes:

```
/ -> HomePage
/sign-in -> SignInPage
/register -> RegisterPage
```

I can call the routes internally via `navigate` which works fine. But I cannot call these routes via `localhost:8910/register` for example. I get a 404 error.

**What do I have to do to make (almost) all routes callable directly with their absolute urls?**

Answer (score 0):

A late response to your question, but all the routes are managed in the `Routes.tsx`-file. In my example, I have a route to access the `BikesPage`-component (located in `.../pages/Bike/BikesPage` hence the naming `BikeBikesPage`).

[image: RedwoodJS routes file]

So to ask your question, to make them callable by their absolute name, the `name` must be the same as the `path`. Hope that helped you or anyone coming here afterwards!